# Increasing outputs of Resnet?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I'm trying to do a CAPTCHA recognition based on this code `https://github.com/shishishu/pytorch-captcha-recognition`. Instead of recognizing 4 characters, I decided to increase to 6 and modified the model.py as follow (here are some parts of it):

```
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inchannel, outchannel, stride=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(inchannel, outchannel, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannel, track_running_stats=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(outchannel, outchannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannel, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or inchannel != outchannel:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(inchannel, outchannel, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannel, track_running_stats=True)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.left(x)
        out += self.shortcut(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out


class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ResidualBlock, num_classes=charLength):
        super().__init__()
        self.inchannel = 64
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64, track_running_stats=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.layer1 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 64, 2, stride=1)
        self.layer2 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 128, 2, stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 256, 2, stride=2)
        self.layer4 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 512, 2, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

    def make_layer(self, block, channels, num_blocks, stride):
        strides = [stride] + [1] * (num_blocks - 1)
        layers = []
        for stride in strides:
            layers.append(block(self.inchannel, channels, stride))
            self.inchannel = channels
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)  # [3, 32, 32] -> [64, 32, 32]
        x = self.layer1(x)  # -> [64, 32, 32] -> [64, 32, 32]
        x = self.layer2(x)  # -> [128, 16, 16] -> [128, 16, 16], floor in conv2d
        x = self.layer3(x)  # -> [256, 8, 8] -> [256, 8, 8]
        x = self.layer4(x)  # -> [512, 4, 4] -> [512, 4, 4]
        x = F.avg_pool2d(x, 4)  # -> [512, 1, 1]
        x = x.view(-1, 512)  # -> [1, 512]
        y1 = self.fc1(x)  # -> [1, 62]
        y2 = self.fc2(x)
        y3 = self.fc3(x)
        y4 = self.fc4(x)
        y5 = self.fc5(x)
        y6 = self.fc6(x)
        return y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6
```

Other files were adjusted as well to get 6 outputs. However, when training, I noticed that the test accuracy is very low when compared to the 4 characters' code. I generated captcha dataset with 6 characters (100K trainset, 10K testset). Example of accuracy of first 5 epochs for 4 characters CAPTCHA (using original code, same amount of dataset):

```
epoch 1, the training loss is 2054.17636
the accuracy of test set is 0.675
epoch 2, the training loss is 312.97247
the accuracy of test set is 0.77109375
epoch 3, the training loss is 201.88016
the accuracy of test set is 0.7998697916666667
epoch 4, the training loss is 154.38759
the accuracy of test set is 0.816015625
epoch 5, the training loss is 123.43352
the accuracy of test set is 0.838671875
```

And this is first 5 epochs when training 6 characters:

```
epoch 1, the training loss is 5583.41545
the accuracy of test set is 0.00068359375
epoch 2, the training loss is 2519.27621
the accuracy of test set is 0.00078125
epoch 3, the training loss is 2051.24451
the accuracy of test set is 0.00068359375
epoch 4, the training loss is 1840.40299
the accuracy of test set is 0.00087890625
epoch 5, the training loss is 1721.26417
the accuracy of test set is 0.00087890625
```

Is this normal behaviour or the code I edited has issue? If so, how can I properly increase the outputs of Resnet?

Edit: turns out some typos caused this. Thanks to @Rika for spotting them.

Comment: Why are you have 6 heads? are you trying to predict 6 simultaneous outputs?

Comment: @Rika yes. I'm trying to predict a 6-character CAPTCHA.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didnt use multilabel classification? it could be a viable option for you.

Comment: @Rika I'll look into this. Thank you.

Comment: Also why do you have 3 `self.fc4(x)` ? is that a typo?

Comment: @Rika yes. Seems like an error in my code as well. I'll edit and try training again.

Comment: @Rika You are right. It is the typo that caused the poor accuracy. It improves a lot now. Thank you for spotting the typo.

Comment: your welcome glad I could help ;)